# Excel auto filter

Tags: c#, excel

I have a problem while filtering the Excel column by year. I tried the below code but didn't get any success, could anybody help me or offer some suggestions on how I can find the year in excel filters.

For example, if I enter '12/30/2016', it will search successfully but I would like to search by year (e.g. '2016').

```
Excel.Range range = WorksheetSource.UsedRange;
range.AutoFilter(29, tByear.Text, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues,test4[0,0], true);
range.AutoFilter(29, tByear.Text, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr, tByear.Text+ "*", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  Excel.Range currentFind = null;
  xlworkSheet.Cells.Find(date,Type.Missing,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
```

Comment: hi rishit , my question is not only to find the value , but it should filter that particular value from that column. i just want to filter the result based on user input . .